# I want to select the tags that I have been chosen ? ( laravel )

Tags: laravel

The idea is I have table **users** and **tags** and the third table called **tag_user** that contains the tags that user-selected, so I want in **edit** select the tags that user-selected using **select2**

I tried this code but does not work:

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
  <option value="{{ $tag }}" {{ $tag->id == auth()->user()->id  ? "selected" : "" }} >{{ $tag->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

The table between the users table and tags in image:

[image]

Comment: so this is a multiselect select?

Comment: Why are you showing us HTML and content of your DB, show us how You do Queries?

Comment: @PiotrekZatorski it's simply ( Tag::all(): )

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yeah it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming User model has a relation with Tags by a method `tags`:

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <option value="{{ $tag }}" {{auth()->user()->tags->find($tag->id)!=null  ? "selected" : "" }} >{{ $tag->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Explanation: `auth()->user()->tags` will return a `Collection` of tags, the ones related to the logged user. Collection has a method `find` which will search inside the collection a object that has as key the value passed as parameter, same as `tags->where('tag_id', '=', $tag->tag_id)` (assuming `tag_id` is the primary key of the tags table).

API reference: https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html

Comment: absolutely, i'll add it to the answer

Comment: And yeah I have tags method in User model it's belongsToMany relation

Comment: Just Edit ( tags-find ) to ( tags->find )